# ¿Cómo puedo conseguir los datos de un json anidado?

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets, jsonobject

Me gustaría traer los datos de un json anidado, este es mi json:

```
JsonObject value = (JsonObject) Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("token", token)
                    .add("installments", cuotas)
                    .add("transaction_amount", valor)
                    .add("description", description)
                    .add("payment_method_id", paymentMethodId)
                    .add("payer", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                            .add("email", correo)
                            .add("identification", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                    .add("number", docNumber)
                                    .add("type", docType))
                    )
                    .add("notification_url", "https://www.suaurl.com/notificacoes/")
                    .addNull("sponsor_id")
                    .add("binary_mode", false)
                    .add("external_reference", "MP0001")
                    .add("statement_descriptor", "MercadoPago")
                    .add("additional_info", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                            .add("items", Json.createArrayBuilder()
                                    .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                            .add("id", "PR0001")
                                            .add("title", "Point Mini")
                                            .add("description", "Producto Point para cobros con tarjetas mediante bluetooth")
                                            .add("picture_url", "https://http2.mlstatic.com/resources/frontend/statics/growth-sellers-landings/device-mlb-point-i_medium@2x.png")
                                            .add("category_id", "electronics")
                                            .add("quantity", 1)
                                            .add("unit_price", valor)
                                    ))
                            .add("payer", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                    .add("first_name", "Nome")
                                    .add("last_name", "Sobrenome")
                                    .add("address", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                            .add("zip_code", "06233-200")
                                            .add("street_name", "Av das Nacoes Unidas")
                                            .add("street_number", 3003)
                                    )
                                    .add("registration_date", "2019-01-01T12:01:01.000-03:00")
                                    .add("phone", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                            .add("area_code", "011")
                                            .add("number", "987654321")
                                    )
                            )
                            .add("shipments", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                    .add("receiver_address", Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                            .add("street_name", "Av das Nacoes Unidas")
                                            .add("street_number", 3003)
                                            .add("zip_code", "06233200")
                                            .add("city_name", "Buzios")
                                            .add("state_name", "Rio de Janeiro")
                                    )
                            )
                    )
```

Me gustaria por ejemplo traer los datos que se encuentran en:

```
.add("items", Json.createArrayBuilder()
                                    .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                            .add("id", "PR0001")
                                            .add("title", "Point Mini")
                                            .add("description", "Producto Point para cobros con tarjetas mediante bluetooth")
                                            .add("picture_url", "https://http2.mlstatic.com/resources/frontend/statics/growth-sellers-landings/device-mlb-point-i_medium@2x.png")
                                            .add("category_id", "electronics")
                                            .add("quantity", 1)
                                            .add("unit_price", valor)
                                    ))
```

Ya sea el *title* la *description* o el id, de esta manera traigo los datos a mi servlet, ejemplo:

```
request.setAttribute("payment_type_id", jsonrta.get("payment_type_id")); 
request.setAttribute("status", jsonrta.get("status"));
```

Pero cuando trato de hacer lo mismo con *title* que esta dentro de ítems me sale el siguiente error:

> Error al traer datos org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["title"] not found.

Retomando a mi pregunta, ¿Cómo puedo traer los datos que están dentro de ítems?.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898768/how-to-access-nested-elements-of-json-object-using-getjsonarray-method) en la comunidad en inglés.

Te haré un resumen basado en esa fuente: Al igual que para obtener valores JSON en otros lenguajes, en java hay que ir propiedad por propiedad hasta llegar "al fondo" Ej:

El json:

[image: Ejemplo JSON anidado]

```
{"primerAtributo":{"atributoAnidado":{"otroAnidadoMas":5}}}
```

En javascrpit, para lelgar al valor 5 se hace así:

```
console.print(miJson.primerAtributo.AtributoAnidado.OtroAnidadoMas);
```

En java, como ya tienes un JsonObject, según la fuente en inglés, tan solo debes hacer esto para llegar a una propiedad JSON anidada:

```
//Primero vamos al primer atributo, luego al anidado y de último al otroAnidadoMas
//es como ir recorriendo uno a uno hasta llegar al deseado.
System.printLn(value.getJSONObject("primerAtributo")
.getJSONArray("atributoAnidado")
.getJSONObject("otroAnidadoMas"));
```

Volviendo al JSON que nos brindaste en la pregunta, debería ser algo así:

```
request.setAttribute("titleEnItems", value.getJSONObject("additional_info")
.getJSONArray("items")
.getJSONObject("title"));
```

Observa que "getJSONObject" y "getJSONArray" trabajan directamente sobre un objeto tipo "JsonObject" (En tu código de ejemplo, value es un objeto así), entonces deberías trabajar directamente sobre él con esos métodos que te estoy comentando.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Tengo el siguiente problema en el .getJSONObject("title")); sale el siguiente error string cannot be converted to int  osea entra hasta intems pero cuando ya voy a pedir el dato que tiene title parece que no reconoce la cadena string y pide un int quedo atento, muchas gracias

Comment: Intentemos cambiar `getJSONObject("title");` por `getJsonString("title");` a ver si funciona.

Comment: **Fuente de la información anterior** [Documentación Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

Comment: Umm no aparece cannot find symbol